# Qual o AVD mais indicado para um app desenvolvido preferencialmente para moto g?

Tags: android, avd

Eu tenho um aparelho moto g e pretendo usá-lo por meio da interface usb para testar um app em desenvolvimento. Mas, por ora, vou usar o emulador. Qual modelo de emulador eu deva usar para ser mais parecido com o moto g?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá!

Existe o Genymotion, na qual você pode baixar diversas isos prontas da forma que estão nos aparelhos originais. Você pode emular o Moto G no Genymotion.

Segue link: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/

Segue passo-a-passo para instalação http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2013/12/veja-como-emular-o-android-no-computador-com-o-genymotion.html

Comment: Obrigadão, Kleyton!